# Postprocess @RequestBody obtained from Jackson in Spring controllers, before @Valid checks kick in

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, jackson

(I'm using Spring 4.0.x)

Lets say I've got the following controller method defined:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseObject postNewRequest(@Valid @RequestBody RequestObject request) {
    return randomService.processRequest(request);
}
```

`RequestObject` is basically a JSON payload, which Jacksons `ObjectMapper` maps to given DTO.

What is the cleanest approach for me modify object which `Jackson` serializes, before validation kicks in and before it gets passed down to the service?

Example use case: I want to be nice and if user provides me with a value which I can safely trim, I want to do this here, instead of worrying about this in the service?

Bonus question: is it possible for this to be specified per `RequestObject` class, not per controller method?

Thank you very much for any help in here and spending time reading this question.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852213/can-jackson-be-configured-to-trim-leading-trailing-whitespace-from-all-string-pr

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan awesome, until I will find a proper solution, this one looks like a viable approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Propably you need to use [HandlerInterceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html)

Or, if you want to make it per RequestObject class, try to use aspects.